# Dynamic arrays: using realloc() without memory leaks

Tags: c, realloc, cppcheck

I use realloc to resize the memory allocated:

```
char **get_channel_name(void)   
{
    char **result;
    int n;

    result = (char **) 0;
    for (elem = snd_mixer_first_elem(handle), n = 0; elem; elem = snd_mixer_elem_next(elem)) {
        if (!snd_mixer_selem_is_active(elem))
            continue;
        if (snd_mixer_selem_has_playback_volume(elem) &&
            snd_mixer_selem_has_playback_switch(elem) &&
            snd_mixer_selem_has_capture_switch(elem)) {
            if (result == (char **) 0)
                result = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));
            else
                result = (char **) realloc(result, sizeof(char *) * (n + 1)); /* nulled but not freed upon failure */
            result[n++] = strdup(snd_mixer_selem_get_name(elem));
        }
    }

    if (result == (char **) 0)
        return NULL;

    result = (char **) realloc(result, sizeof(char *) * (n + 1)); /* nulled but not freed upon failure */
    result[n] = NULL;

    return result;
}
```

When I check code with cppcheck tool static C/C++ code analysis, printed the following warings:

```
Common realloc mistake: 'result' nulled but not freed upon failure
```

How can I fix these 2 possible memory leaks?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `realloc()` fails it returns `NULL`.

So if you do (and assuming `realloc()` would fail)

```
result = realloc(result, ...);
```

`result` will be assigned `NULL` and what it pointed to is not `free()`ed and the address to be `free()`ed is lost.

To fix this do:

```
{
  void * tmp = realloc(result, ...);
  if (NULL == tmp)
  {
    /* Handle error case, propably freeing what result is pointing to. */
  }
  else
  {
    result = tmp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick to fixing the "nulled but not freed upon failure" error is to store the value returned by `realloc` into a separate pointer, and check it for `NULL` before reassigning the old pointer:

```
char **tmp = (char **) realloc(result, sizeof(char *) * (n + 1));
if (tmp) {
    result = tmp;
} else {
    ... // Handle reallocation error
}
```

Now that the assignment of `result` is protected by `NULL` check, you have the old value to work with: you could `free` it if you want, or you could continue using it if you need to. The original code, on the other hand, does not give you the same option.

**Note:** When you pass `NULL` pointer to `realloc`, it behaves like `malloc`. That's why you can drop the conditional in the first use of `realloc` - replace this

```
if (result == (char **) 0)
    result = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *));
else
    result = (char **) realloc(result, sizeof(char *) * (n + 1));
```

with this:

```
char** tmep = (char **) realloc(result, sizeof(char *) * (n + 1));
... // check temp and assign result here
```

Don't forget to set `n` to zero - currently, it's used uninitialized, which is undefined behavior.