# C modern array allocation?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have some code to create a new struct and allocate some space for an array of structs. Initially, I allocate space for 1 struct on the array:

```
static int datasetCount = 0;

int datasetgroup_new(DatasetGroup *dg char *id){

  dg->id = id;

  // Allocate space for a single dataset to start with
  dg->datasets = (Dataset *) malloc(sizeof(Dataset));

  return 0;

}
```

I then have a function to add another struct ('dataset') to the struct containing the array. At the end of the function, I reallocate the array to provide another space:

```
void datasetgroup_add(DatasetGroup *dg, string filePath){

  // Create the dataset
  Dataset ds;
  dataset_new(&ds, filePath);

  // Copy the dataset to the dataset array
  dg->datasets[datasetCount] = ds;

  // Increment the dataset counter
  datasetCount++;

  //Grow the array
  dg->datasets = (Dataset *)realloc(dg->datasets, sizeof(Dataset) * (datasetCount + 1));

}
```

I keeping reading things that hint that in modern C you don't need to do stuff like this.
I may be wrong...so is the a more modern/correct way to do this?

Edit:

Sorry, to be clear that I am not using C++ types, I have created a typedef for `string`:

```
typedef char* string;
```

Comment: Where do you read that? In C++, you have `new` and `delete`, but there are no such things in C.

Comment: generally the approach is correct for C. You could use a library that would hide all the hassle under the hood.

Comment: and, if you actually use C++, I would recommend to take a look at the standard [containers library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and use a container that better fits your specific needs

Comment: No, string is:  `typedef char* string`. Sorry, I will edit to be clearer

Comment: Then if you need a pure-C solution I would use a helper library like [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html)

Comment: But this is only a helper, a wrapper, internally it performs the same boring operations like those in your code.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) there is nothing for this in modern C (C11) standard but you can use libraries like [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/) in order to easier memory management or you can use it's data structures like [array](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/glib-Arrays.html).

If you use visual studio may be you could find some non-standard function for this in that.

To be more specified in linux, these functions just wrapper for `brk()` system call and all of them do memory management in user space and their speed and efficiently depend on their algorithms, for example GNU C Library get some space in heap and then manage it for you so not all of your `realloc()` call end into `brk()` system call, so do not worry yourself about their efficiently so much. you can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) in order to see your memory profiling.

Answer (score 3):

I am not clear what you mean by modern C, however there are two things in the code that I want to mention.

The usage style of `realloc` is wrong. In case it fails and returns NULL, then the original memory would be leaked. See, for example, [Dynamic arrays: using realloc() without memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589846/dynamic-arrays-using-realloc-without-memory-leaks)

The logic of growing memory invokes `realloc` and thus memory allocation on every addition (i.e. call to `datasetgroup_add`). It increases the size/capacity of the dynamic array by one. This may not be ideal. The commonly used idiom for growing such memory is to double it whenever the capacity becomes full. That way, cost of memory allocation is [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) ([What is amortized analysis of algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102585/what-is-amortized-analysis-of-algorithms)) over all the calls.

Comment: Do you mean [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) rather than memoized?

Comment: Yes, no doubt. Thank you!

Comment: @Arun thanks. Your comments on the use of realloc are helpful. For growing memory, I was aware this is relatively costly, however in the context of this program, the processing time required after this array has been fully populated is much much greater than the cost of populating the array.